# firefox selectionchange event for textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, textselection

Listening for [selectionchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/selectionchange_event) events in a `textarea` works in chrome and safari, but not in firefox.

```
<div>selecting me will detect your selecting!</div>
<textarea>alas, I will not!</textarea>
<div id="f"></div>
```

```
document.addEventListener( 'selectionchange', function() {
  document.getElementById('f').innerHTML += '<br>selecting';
});
```

What event should I be listening for instead?

**demo**

https://codepen.io/jedierikb/pen/XWXxmZW

Comment: https://github.com/Automattic/selectionchange-polyfill

Comment: https://github.com/w3c/selection-api/issues/53

Comment: It works in my firefox 95.

Comment: @Friedrich yep, it appears this has been resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While document 'selectionchange' events do not fire in firefox textareas, textareas themselves can listen for 'select' events, which fire the same event types.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/select_event